# How can I download data using ftp to a spreadsheet with VBA for Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ftp

I have found the code below to start me off with developing a automated way to download files from an ftp site. however it fails every time without any error that i can troubleshoot.

I have a newbie in excel vba so some help would be appreciated.

I have tried searching online and here at stack overflow but I could'nt figure this out on my own

```
Private Const FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_UNKNOWN As Long = 0
Private Const INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD As Long = &H80000000

Private Declare Function InternetOpenA Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
                                ByVal sAgent As String, _
                                ByVal lAccessType As Long, _
                                ByVal sProxyName As String, _
                                ByVal sProxyBypass As String, _
                                ByVal lFlags As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function InternetConnectA Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
            ByVal hInternetSession As Long, _
            ByVal sServerName As String, _
            ByVal nServerPort As Long, _
            ByVal sUsername As String, _
            ByVal sPassword As String, _
            ByVal lService As Long, _
            ByVal lFlags As Long, _
            ByVal lcontext As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function FtpGetFileA Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
                            ByVal hConnect As Long, _
                            ByVal lpszRemoteFile As String, _
                            ByVal lpszNewFile As String, _
                            ByVal fFailIfExists As Long, _
                            ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Long, _
                            ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
                            ByVal dwContext As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function InternetCloseHandle Lib "wininet" ( _
                            ByVal hInet As Long) As Long


Sub FtpDownload(ByVal strRemoteFile As String, ByVal strLocalFile As String, ByVal strHost As String, ByVal lngPort As Long, Optional ByVal strUser As String, Optional ByVal strPass As String)
    Dim hOpen As Long
    Dim hConn As Long

hOpen = InternetOpenA("FTPGET", 1, vbNullString, vbNullString, 1)
hConn = InternetConnectA(hOpen, strHost, lngPort, strUser, strPass, 1, 0, 2)

If FtpGetFileA(hConn, strRemoteFile, strLocalFile, 1, 0, FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_UNKNOWN Or INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD, 0) Then
    Debug.Print "Success"
Else
    Debug.Print "Fail"
End If

'Close connections
InternetCloseHandle hConn
InternetCloseHandle hOpen

End Sub

Sub Get_File_From_FTP()

'Assign Host URL, Source and Destination File path
Dim HostURL, fileSource, FileDestination As String
HostURL = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
fileSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2)
FileDestination = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 2)
FtpDownload fileSource, FileDestination, HostURL, 21, "Username", "Password"

End Sub
```

Comment: The above code needs to be edited to be readable.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I will have a look at your suggestion and let you know how it went.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the above code works without any problems. I believe the problem might be within your reference cells...

```
HostURL = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
fileSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2)
FileDestination = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(2, 2)
```

When i messed around with this, i found that I had to have this format...

```
HostURL = "192.168.168.2" 'Or your FQDN
fileSource = "/This/Is/The/Path/To/Your/File.file" ' Make sure that this matches your file path
FileDestination = "C:\This\Is\The\Complete\Path\On\Your\Machine.File"
```

Of course, make sure that you populate the username and password section of the macro...

```
FtpDownload fileSource, FileDestination, HostURL, 21, "YOUR_USERNAME_HERE", "YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE"
```

Comment: Hi, This still isnt working for me, because of Data protection I cant post the domain etc so you can help to troubleshoot. I suspect that its my path that are wrong, is there a way  to get what is being sent to get the data via the FTP.

Comment: I have a working path that if i use manually it works however when i pass the specific paths it doesn't.

Comment: If your FileDestination alraedy exists, then this function WILL fail to pull any FTP data. Again, double check your hostURL, filesource, and file destination. Each of these should match the above example.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim HostURL, fileSource, FileDestination As String
    HostURL = "ftp.datacentre.com"
    fileSource = "/country_forecast/CWG_ecop_19021012_United-Kingdom.csv"
    FileDestination = "C:\Development\Test1\newFile.txt"

FtpDownload fileSource, FileDestination, HostURL, 21, "username", "password"
```

I have tried everything now. so I'm using the above paths. 
This url works though I i download the file manually. [ftp://username:password@ftp.datacentre.com/country_forecast/CWG_ecop_19021012_United-Kingdom.csv]